# How do I recursively define a Hash in Ruby from supplied arguments?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, hash-of-hashes

This snippet of code populates an `@options` hash. `values` is an `Array` which contains zero or more heterogeneous items. If you invoke `populate` with arguments that are `Hash` entries, it uses the value you specify for each entry to assume a default value.

```
def populate(*args)
  args.each do |a|
    values = nil
    if (a.kind_of? Hash)
      # Converts {:k => "v"} to `a = :k, values = "v"`
      a, values = a.to_a.first
    end

    @options[:"#{a}"] ||= values ||= {}
  end
end
```

What I'd like to do is change `populate` such that it *recursively* populates `@options`. There is a special case: if the values it's about to populate a key with are an Array consisting entirely of (1) Symbols or (2) Hashes whose keys are Symbols (or some combination of the two), then they should be treated as *subkeys* rather than the values associated with that key, and the same logic used to evaluate the original `populate` arguments should be recursively re-applied.

That was a little hard to put into words, so I've written some test cases. Here are some test cases and the expected value of `@options` afterwards:

```
populate :a
=> @options is {:a => {}}

populate :a => 42
=> @options is {:a => 42}

populate :a, :b, :c
=> @options is {:a => {}, :b => {}, :c => {}}

populate :a, :b => "apples", :c
=> @options is {:a => {}, :b => "apples", :c => {}}

populate :a => :b
=> @options is {:a => :b}

# Because [:b] is an Array consisting entirely of Symbols or
# Hashes whose keys are Symbols, we assume that :b is a subkey
# of @options[:a], rather than the value for @options[:a].
populate :a => [:b]
=> @options is {:a => {:b => {}}}

populate :a => [:b, :c => :d]
=> @options is {:a => {:b => {}, :c => :d}}

populate :a => [:a, :b, :c]
=> @options is {:a => {:a => {}, :b => {}, :c => {}}}

populate :a => [:a, :b, "c"]
=> @options is {:a => [:a, :b, "c"]}

populate :a => [:one], :b => [:two, :three => "four"]
=> @options is {:a => :one, :b => {:two => {}, :three => "four"}}

populate :a => [:one], :b => [:two => {:four => :five}, :three => "four"]
=> @options is {:a => :one,
                :b => {
                   :two => {
                      :four => :five
                      }
                   },
                   :three => "four"
                }
               }
```

It is acceptable if the signature of `populate` needs to change to accommodate some kind of recursive version. There is no limit to the amount of nesting that could theoretically happen.

Any thoughts on how I might pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

So here's some simple code that works.

```
def to_value args
  ret = {}
  # make sure we were given an array
  raise unless args.class == Array
  args.each do |arg|
    case arg
    when Symbol
      ret[arg] = {} 
    when Hash
      arg.each do |k,v|
        # make sure that all the hash keys are symbols
        raise unless k.class == Symbol
        ret[k] = to_value v 
      end           
    else    
      # make sure all the array elements are symbols or symbol-keyed hashes
      raise         
    end     
  end
  ret
rescue
  args
end
def populate *args
  @options ||= {}
  value = to_value(args)
  if value.class == Hash
    @options.merge! value
  end
end
```

It does deviate from your test cases:

- test case `populate :a, :b => "apples", :c` is a ruby syntax error.  Ruby will assume the *final* argument to a method is a hash (when not given braces), but not a non-final one, as you assume here.  The given code is a syntax error (no matter the definition of `populate`) since it assumes `:c` is a hash key, and finds an end of line when it's looking for `:c`'s value.   `populate :a, {:b => "apples"}, :c` works as expected
- test case `populate :a => [:one], :b => [:two, :three => "four"]` returns `{:a=>{:one=>{}}, :b=>{:two=>{}, :three=>"four"}}`.  This is consistent with the test case `populate :a => [:b]`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby isn't Perl, `=>` works only inside real Hash definition or as final argument in method call. Most things you want will result in a syntax error.

Are you sure that `populate` limited to cases supported by Ruby syntax is worth it?